# Prove() method of Z3?

Tags: z3

Z3 has a `prove()` method, that can prove the equivalence of two formulas.

However, I cannot find technical documentation of this `prove()` method. What is the definition of "equivalence" that `prove()` is using behind the scene ? Is that the "partial equivalence" (proposed in the "Regression Verification" paper), or something more powerful ?

A reminder, the "partial equivalence" guarantees that two formulas are equivalent if given the same input, they produce the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "Regression Verification", we are checking whether a newer version of a *program* produces the same output as the earlier one. That is, it is an approach for checking *program equivalence*. 
In this approach, theorem provers (SMT solvers) such as Z3 are used. That being said, we should not confuse *program equivalence* with *formula equivalence* in first-order logic. Z3 processes first-order logic formulas. [First-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) has well defined semantics. A key concept is satisfiability. For example, the formula `p or q` is satisfiable, because we can make it true by assigning `p` or `q` to true. On the other hand, `p and (not p)` is unsatisfiable. We can find additional information in [this section of the Z3 tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorialcontent/guide#h26).

The Z3 API provides procedures for checking the satisfiability of first-order formulas. The Z3 Python interface has a `prove` procedure. It shows that a formula is valid by showing that its negation is unsatisfiable. This is a simple function built on top of the Z3 API. [Here is a link](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/namespacez3py.html#a21b6ef52d707f1d6197271a212546c23) to its documentation.The documentation was automatically generated from the PyDoc annotations in the code.

Note that, `prove(F)` is checking whether a formula `F` is valid or not. Thus, we can use `prove(F == G)` to try to prove that two *first-order* formulas `F` and `G` are equivalent. That is, we are essentially showing that `F iff G` is a valid formula.

Comment: Leo, I tried to find the definition of "equivalent formulas", but to no avail. I always understand that two formulas are equivalent if they get the same output given the same input. But now it seems my understanding is wrong. Could you elaborate this a little bit on the definition of formula equivalence?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Your intuition is essentially correct. However, we have to make precise the notion of "input" for a first-order formula. This is accomplished by defining *first-order structures*, that provide "meaning" for the free symbols in a formula. In this setting, two formulas are equivalent if they evaluate to the same value in every structure. You can find the precise definition in Model Theory books (Hodges' book is excellent), or searching "first-order structure" and/or "model theory". When a first-order structure `S` makes `F` evaluate to true, we say `S` is a model for `F`.